# Attribute binding using vue.js

Tags: vue.js

I want to bind an image using binding attribute. But reason is that when i run my code it show the Unexpected identifier error

this is my index.html file code

```html
<div id='app'>
    <h2>{{product}}</h2>

    <div class="flex-container">
        <div class="product">
            <div class="product-image">
                <img v-bind:src="image"/>
            </div>
        <div class="product-info">

        </div>
    </div>
</div>  

</div>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/vue/1.0.18/vue.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="main.js"></script>
```

This is main.js code

```js
var app = new Vue({
  el: '#app',
  data: {
    product: 'Socks'
    image : "./img/1.png"
  }
})
```

Comment: Replace the main.js with the below JS code.
`var app = new Vue({
  el: '#app',
  data: {
    product: 'Socks',
    image : "./img/1.png"
  }
})`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
var app = new Vue({
  el: '#app',
  data: {
    product: 'Socks',
    image : "./img/1.png"
  }
})
```

You are missing a comma after the product ppty -- 'Socks'

You can check the fiddle here.
https://jsfiddle.net/p0dynL8o/

Comment: Tony Tom yes i miss this i actually also solve this before seeing your ans but thanks a lot to reply my minor problem bundle of thanks...

Comment: Always double-check before posting questions. happy that you resolved the issue.